# Django basic WSGI Handler for GAE setup

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I've been searching and trying for about 3 hours to get this setup and nothing seems to work. Can someone please just post a basic main.app and app.yaml file to get started with Python 2.7/Django 1.2 on GAE.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an example in the Rietveld source code:
http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/source/browse/main.py?name=py27#65

The app.yaml line that selects this is here:
http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/source/browse/app.yaml?name=py27#30

Note that the Django version is also selected in app.yaml:
http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/source/browse/app.yaml?name=py27#42

Answer (score 0):

You [should use](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django) django-nonrel if you want to use django in AppEngine. Their installation page for AppEngine is [here](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#installation).

I have put a [simple script](https://github.com/JuhaS/djangoappengine-script/blob/master/create_djgae.sh) to Github to automatize some of the steps in the guide.

Comment: I appreciate your advice and I'm aware of django-nonrel, but I have specifically chosen not to use it. BTW, you can find a multi-platform python script that installs django-nonrel and doesn't require mercurial here: http://bitbucket.org/Sepero/install-django-nonrel